# robots communicating with each other

Tags: communication, robotics

Is there any possible way of designing robots that can communicate with each other? As in, one of the robot can be programmed to act as a master, while the other robot, situated somewhere else, can be programmed to act as a slave and obey the commands given by the master to him?

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you done so far?

Comment: Haven't done anything so far. I'm a computer engineering student currently studying in my third year. This idea just popped into my mind. So thought, I could ask it here.

Comment: No, there is no way. A new EU directive has made it illegal for robots to communicate with each other.

Comment: Unless they reeeeeally want to talk, then exceptions may be made.

Comment: Imagine this very unreal  and funny situation. I have 3 robots, one stationed in my cabin in front of me, the other 2 being stationed near a water cooler inside the office far away from the cabin. I ask my cabin bot to get me a glass of water. The bot checks which of the 2 robots is idle and then tells it to get me a glass of water.

Comment: stack exchange is a really bad option for hypothetical type questions...

Comment: haha, well that was just an idea that came into my mind, thought its worth sharing here

Answer (score 3):

You are basically asking how two objects/circuits can communicate with each other. There are of course many ways this can be accomplished:

1. Wired communication: SPI, I2C, UART, RS-232, etc.
2. Wireless communication: 2.4Ghz, Sub-Ghz, Infrared transmission, etc.

Clarifying what exactly are the application of the robots, the environment, the desired distance between them, etc. could help decide on a specific answer/recommendation.

Comment: well, the prime purpose i was thinking of, as i said earlier, to create a master slave environment in an office probably. something working similar to LAN in computing, where you can send messages to systems in your LAN, provided you have the privileges, although in a wireless manner.

Comment: "Similar to LAN, although wireless"? You've never heard of wireless LANs? Does Wi-Fi ring any bells? Has it occurred to you that robots could just be on a LAN?

Answer (score 1):

Robots are nothing more than computers with actuators. If computers can be in a master-slave relationship, then robots can be in a master-slave relationship.

Answer (score 0):

There are many flavors of communication between robots. The internet of things applies to robots as well as your standard household items.

You could: 
Build a master device that would act as a bridge or router.

It could use wifi on one side to communicate to the internet to receive commands or transmit data.

It could then on the other side have a zigbee device that would receive data and transmit instructions to the slave devices you mention.

But you could also setup a hive type network where the queen has a directive or directives and it uses the slaves / drones to complete the directive. You could use simple IR or something like zigbee to accomplish this and not need internet connectivity.

It all depends on the variables as to which type of network you use. Zigbee if you need a mesh network, wifi if you need bandwidth and power, or IR if you will have line of site and need a cheap solution.